# How to open a same window as childwindow and when closed enable parent window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a window that opens a pop up and what i want is open the popup as child window or window on top of another and disable the back window? so that somebody cannot go back and close the Main window.

I tried putting the window top most but still i am able to close the main window.

```
private void axWebBrowser1_NewWindow3(object sender, DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow2Event e)
{
    BrowserWindow window = new BrowserWindow();
    window.axWebBrowser1.RegisterAsBrowser = true;
    window.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    window.textBox.IsEnabled = false;
    window.Height = 550;
    window.Width = 600;
    e.ppDisp = window.axWebBrowser1.Application;
    window.Topmost = true;            
}
```

Comment: Set the other windows' IsEnabled property to false.  You'll need to use the Closing event of the popup to re-enable them.

Comment: that dint work because its the same window thats opening again. So thats the problem i cannot keep track of methods and context.

Comment: At what point are you Showing your form? Are you using WinForms or WPF? You tagged both in the question tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does setting the owner of the child window help?

```
private void axWebBrowser1_NewWindow3(object sender, DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow2Event e)
{
    BrowserWindow window = new BrowserWindow();
    window.Owner = this;
    ...          
}
```

Comment: That worked Thanks!! it closes the child window on main window thats okay for me..

Answer (score 0):

When you display the child window, display it as a modal window, using the
[Form.ShowDialog Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx). There's no need to disable the parent window then, as the child window being shown as a modal window would make the parent window not accessible until the modal window is closed.

```
BrowserWindow window = new BrowserWindow();
window.ShowDialog();
```

If modal doesn't work for you for some reason try something like this. I'm unsure of why you can't use modal, need to understand your requirement a little more.

```
private void axWebBrowser1_NewWindow3(object sender, DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow2Event e)
{
    BrowserWindow window = new BrowserWindow();

    // in your case I think the parent form should be = this.
    Form parentForm = this;    
    window.Tag = parentForm;
    window.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.BrowserWindow_FormClosing);

    parentForm.Enabled = false;
}

private void BrowserWindow_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Form parentWindow = (sender as Form).Tag;
    parentWindow.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: that dint work either its messing up my context because of the object of the same class.

Comment: the Method that i have shown is only opening the Window and the Method is inside the same class BrowserWindow. So if i make another instance of the same class and show the same window as in the code above how can i disable the previous window and enable it when its closed?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand why modal doesn't work for you. If I'm reading this correctly, also try handling the Form.Closing event when you create the new instance of BrowserWindow. You could set the parent window as a Tag of it when you instantiate it, and then when you respond to the closing, make the parent window enabled again by grabbing the instance from the tag.

Comment: this is like if i do set an IsEnabled property still i can go back to parent form and close it.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean. Please provide more code if possible so we can see the whole issue.

Comment: the thing is the window is not a normal winform window its a wpf window.

Comment: Oh ok. The original post had a WinForms tag on it. It's probably quite the same in WPF, I'm not sure haven't used it much.

Comment: Sorry about that i have edited the tag... it was because converting windows to wpf